# Filter MySQL queries by count of 2 columns

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
select id, store_id, name from ads 
where name regexp '^.*(Massa+.*effect+)|(Glutamina+.*Black+.*Belt+).*$';
```

The result is:

```
 id | store_id | name
----|----------|-----------------
 94 |        9 | Massa effect
 96 |        9 | Glutamina black belt
131 |        1 | Glutamina black belt
143 |       55 | Massa effect
```

I need a query that returns the both products searched (Massa effect and Glutamina black belt) that belongs the same Store (store_id).

In the example, I want the results to be:

```
 id | store_id | name
----|----------|-----------------
 94 |        9 | Massa effect
 96 |        9 | Glutamina black belt
```

**EDIT**

Some example of data that I have on this table:

```
 id | store_id | name
----|----------|-----------------
  2 |        4 | iPhone
 91 |        9 | Sweet sweat
 94 |        9 | Massa effect
 96 |        9 | Glutamina black belt
102 |        9 | BCCA 2500
131 |        1 | Glutamina black belt
143 |       55 | Massa effect
147 |       55 | Massa Effect
200 |       77 | Hey
202 |       78 | Topster
206 |       55 | Massa X
```

Comment: You should specify your question in greater detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if this is what you want but you can try something like this:

```
SELECT id, store_id, name 
FROM ads
WHERE name regexp '^.*(Massa+.*effect+)|(Glutamina+.*Black+.*Belt+).*$'
    AND EXISTS(
        SELECT null FROM ads as a WHERE 
        name regexp 
        '^.*(Massa+.*effect+)|(Glutamina+.*Black+.*Belt+).*$'
       AND a.id != ads.id
       AND a.store_id = ads.store_id
);
```

I am sorry for the formatting.
The general idea is to use an "exists" to check if there is another element in the table that has similar properties, but not being the row itself. If you want to make sure that name is not the same, you can add another condition to the where clause `a.name != ads.name`

Comment: This is a great solution! When I added your last suggestion (`a.name != ads.name`) I have exactly the results that I expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GROUP BY in combination with HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 to find duplicated store_id in combination with the REGEX.

**Query**

```
SELECT
 *
FROM 
 ads 
WHERE 
 store_id IN (
  SELECT 
   store_id
  FROM ( 

    SELECT
      store_id
    FROM
      ads 
    WHERE
      name
    REGEXP '^.*(Massa+.*effect+)|(Glutamina+.*Black+.*Belt+).*$'
  ) 
    ads
  GROUP BY
    ads.store_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

**Result**

```
| id | store_id |                 name |
|----|----------|----------------------|
| 94 |        9 |         Massa effect |
| 96 |        9 | Glutamina black belt |
```

demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3ca8/9

**Edit:**

Made a update using GROUP_CONCAT to get the search id's and later on JOIN them back on the same table with FIND_IN_SET

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 ads.*
FROM ( 

  SELECT 
     store_id
   , GROUP_CONCAT(id) ids
  FROM ( 

    SELECT 
     *
    FROM (     
      SELECT
          id
        , store_id
      FROM
        ads 
      WHERE
        name
      REGEXP '^.*(Massa+.*effect+)|(Glutamina+.*Black+.*Belt+).*$'
    ) 
      ads
  ) 
   ads
  GROUP BY 
   store_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
)
 ads_search
INNER JOIN 
 ads
ON
 FIND_IN_SET(id, ids)
```

**Result**

```
| id | store_id |                 name |
|----|----------|----------------------|
| 94 |        9 |         Massa effect |
| 96 |        9 | Glutamina black belt |
```

demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3ca8/22

Comment: your solution is great, but does not works if there are other products in table belongs the store. The Store 9 (store_id = 9) have many others products in this table, all returned in this query.

Comment: @Antonello try the updated query should select better because it has a better filter..but because off the JOIN with FIND_IN_SET it would scale on larger tables... can you provide better example data so i could figure out a better solution i there is anny.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add another constraint to your query.

```
SELECT
    id,
    store_id,
    name
FROM
    ads 
WHERE
    name regexp '^.*(Massa+.*effect+)|(Glutamina+.*Black+.*Belt+).*$'
    AND store_id = 9;
```

Comment: Don't think the topic starter wants this.